# webview2 refuses to work in visual studio 2017 .net winforms

Tags: winforms

I have added WebView2 to my visual Studio 2017 VB.NET solution with .NET 4.7.2, as per the instructions on microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms

When I put the webview2 on my form and hit F5 to run it, I always get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

and it is stuck in application in break mode.

Can anyone tell me how to make it work please?  Or am I stupid and it will only work in visual studio 2019 with core?

Comment: You have to Initialize `CoreWebView2`, that's what is usually null. You need and async method that can `await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();`. This calls the Loader. Check whether you have `Prefer 32-bit` set in your Project's Properties, since you may need to copy `WebView2Loader.dll` with the right bitness in your Project's build Folders (`\bin\debug` and `\bin\release`). You also need to have the correct version of Edge in your machine.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about the Loader location. The last NuGet Package should configure a specific repository in your current build profile, so the .dll may be removed if you add a copy manually. Anyway, when you call the initialization procedure, you should have a response about these details.